# I Want To Make Calculator Bot Using PyQt5 And I am getting Error

Tags: python, pyqt5, typeerror, python-3.6

I Want To Make Calculator Bot  Using PyQt5 And I am getting This Error.
Can U Help Me??

P.S I am Begginer in PyQt5

My Error Is This:

```
TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
```

And My Code Is This:

```
class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.dialog = QComboBox()
        self.lbl = QLabel("Choose Gas Name:")
        self.but = QPushButton("Calculate")
        self.litre = QLineEdit(self)
        self.regular = QLabel("Regular >>> "+str(2.27))
        self.euro_reg = QLabel("Euro Regular >>> "+str(2.33))
        self.diesel = QLabel("Diesel >>> "+str(2.39))
        self.calculated = QLabel("")
        self.init_ui()
    def init_ui(self):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.regular)
        layout.addWidget(self.euro_reg)
        layout.addWidget(self.diesel)
        layout.addWidget(self.litre)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl)
        layout.addWidget(self.dialog)
        layout.addWidget(self.but)
        layout.addWidget(self.calculated)

        self.dialog.addItem("Regular")
        self.dialog.addItem("Euro Regular")
        self.dialog.addItem("Diesel")
        self.setGeometry(100,100,200,200)
        self.but.clicked.connect(self.calculate)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()
    def calculate(self, layout):
        if self.litre.text() == "":
            self.calculated.setText("<font color=red>Please Enter Litre")
        else:
            litre_int = int(self.litre.text())
            self.calculated.setText(litre_int*int(2.27))
```

Comment: you should convert the  parameter in the last line to obtain a string : `self.calculated.setText(str(litre_int*int(2.27)))`

Answer (score 1):

`setText` expects a string, not an int. You need to explicitly convert the result to a string:

```
self.calculated.setText(str(litre_int*int(2.27)))
# Here -----------------^
```